# DateTime get the letters representing day, month, year from the currentculture

Tags: c#, excel, globalization, cultureinfo

I would like to write a method that gives me the 3 letters - representing the day, month, year - from a datetimeformat.

So in en-US culture my desired return values would be (plus the separator)

- d
- M
- y
- /

in de-DE the same method should return

- T (**T**ag = day)
- M (**M**onat = month)
- J (**J**ahr = year)
- . (Separator)

I had a look into the [DateTimeFormatInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class form [CurrentCulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.datetimeformat(v=vs.110).aspx) but could only find the separator do you have any idea how I can get the rest?

```
var culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
Console.WriteLine(culture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator);
```

I need this because the **TEXT** function inside **Excel** doesn't accept the format from the InvariantCulture and only handles it from the currentculture.

So something like this isn't valid in german Excel version:

```
=TEXT(NOW();"dd.MM.yyyy")
```

this needs to be set with

```
=TEXT(NOW();"TT.MM.JJJJ")
```

(it doesn't matter if its done with VBA, it doesn't get translated)
You can have a look at the following http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win013.htm

The string format can be anything since the user can input it as he likes and I need to translate it to the current culture.

Comment: which format string are you using? the key values don't change with culture.

Comment: that doesn't exist in .net - perhaps you could write something on your own.

Comment: @DanielA.White how would you do it, with simple string manipulation and how would that method look like, what properties would you look at, I don't really know all cultures where it could be different and a string manipulation method that's valid for every culture and every user could have changed his settings to something totally random.

Comment: could this answer help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15665449/23528

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/917519/165333 has some workarounds that use VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in VBA:
DateTimeStrings will return an array of the date codes and separator.

```
Option Explicit
Function DateTimeStrings() As Variant
    Dim s(3)
    With Application
        s(0) = .International(xlDayCode)
        s(1) = .International(xlMonthCode)
        s(2) = .International(xlYearCode)
        s(3) = .International(xlDateSeparator)
    End With

DateTimeStrings = s

Debug.Print s(0), s(1), s(2), s(3)

End Function
```

**EDIT:**  I'm not sure how you want to use this, but, for example, to insert a formula similar to what you have above, (eg:  `=TEXT(A1,"dd/mm/yyy")` in B1 and in the appropriate language, you could select A1 and run the following macro:

=============================================

```
Sub AddTextFunction()
    Dim R As Range, C As Range
    Dim sFormula As String
    Dim V As Variant
     Dim D As String, M As String, Y As String, sep As String

Set R = Selection

For Each C In R
    V = DateTimeStrings()
        D = V(0)
        M = V(1)
        Y = V(2)
        sep = V(3)

    sFormula = "=text(RC[-1],""" & D & D & sep & M & M & sep & Y & Y & Y & """)"
    C.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = sFormula
Next C

End Sub
```

===================================================

Comment: Very nice.  I was unaware of the `International` property and even less aware of how it might be useful.