# Format Date not working

Tags: excel

I have a problem formatting the date in excel. No matter what you do, the date stays the same and we cannot filter by date because of it.

Any assistance will be appreciated. This is a system generated excel with NO macros or formatting

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `TEXT()` function quite easily (Note: source data must be an excel date value)

```
TEXT(value, format_text)
```

where `value` is the reference cell and `format_text` is how you want to format the text- in your case dd/mm/yyyy.

Assuming:

```
A1 = 3/17/2013
A2 = 12/27/2013
```

In B1 & B2 simply input:

```
B1 = TEXT(A1, "dd/mm/yyyy")
B2 = TEXT(A2, "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

and the result should be

```
     A              B
3/17/2013      17/03/2013
12/27/2013     27/12/2013
```

Hope that helps.

UPDATED SUGGESTION IF WORKING WITH TEXT:

Split the string using `mid()`, `left()` and `right()` functions then check to see if the month mm is 1 or 2 characters long using the `LEN()` function. Finally concatenatr the string together using the & and / operators.

Try pasting this in B1, it should work fine:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("/",A1,1)+1,2)&"/"&IF(LEN(LEFT(A1,FIND("/",A1)-1))=1,0
&LEFT(A1,FIND("/",A1)-1),LEFT(A1,FIND("/",A1)-1))&"/"&RIGHT(A1,4)
```

[Excel Date Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664709/excel-date-formatting)