# Excel: Format TODAY() / DATE

Tags: excel, date, format

1) I would expect in E14 "Today is 13.09.2016", because E16 is formatted as DATE (customer)! But there is a general number instead of date. Why is Excel not able to copy the content of E16 !! How can I get the date in this position?

PS: If you suggest me `="today is "&today()`, then please explain me, how I can  format the date in YYYYMMDD as in the screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: As a workaround, does ="today is "&MID(E16,1,4) &MID(E16,5,2)&MID(E16,7,2) work?

Comment: NO, same error as below "screenshot"

Answer (score 5):

You need to use another function to apply formatting, try the following:

="today is " & TEXT(TODAY(), "yyyymmdd")

More info:

[Excel Date Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664709/excel-date-formatting)

Answer (score 2):

1. Put `=TODAY()` in A1.
2. Tap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+1 and format A1 as Number, Custom, Type: `To\d\a\y i\s yyyymmdd`

[image: this_is_today]

You will display **This is 20160913** but retain the underlying raw date that can be used in calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code

```
="today is "&TEXT(E16,"yyyy-mm-dd")
```

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/513984-linked-text-today-problem.html

Comment: The logic here is that it is text in the cell, so it needs to be text. And text function needs the format to be specified.