# Change The data format in a cell

Tags: excel, vba, date

My date format is like mm-dd-yyyy(eg. 08-22-2020) but date entered as dd-mm-yyyy format (eg.  22-08-2020). I need to convert this format into something like this (eg. 22-Aug-2020)

Comment: Do you intend to use VBA approach?

Comment: There's a full list of VBA Format codes here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications - abbreviated month is localized and is 'mmm'.

Comment: I would say the answer to your question is possibly _You can't_. At least I do not know how to convert _08-22-2020_ into _08-Aug-2020_. Having said that please look at https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/03/11/change-date-format-excel/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664709/excel-date-formatting for possible answers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you need to localize or is English assumed?

Answer (score 1):

You have some options:

Formula based answer: `=TEXT(A1,"DD-MMM-YYYY")`

VBA based answer #1 (Change "Sheet1" to the correct worksheet): `Workbooks(Thisworkbook).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Formula = "=TEXT(A1,""DD-MMM-YYYY"")"`

VBA based answer #2 (Change "Sheet1" to the correct worksheet): `Workbooks(Thisworkbook).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a1").NumberFormat = "DD-MMM-YYYY"`